# How to make this .bat script run on background?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have this script that sets wallpaper every 10 minutes:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 10 /TN MyTaskName /TR "D:/ChangeWallpaper.bat"
```

the **ChangeWallpaper.java**:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d D:\plouzane-1758197.jpg /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

But each time it runs, terminal windows briefly appears. Is there a way to make it run completely invisibly?

Comment: Batch processing have no instruments to hide CMD window. Convert your batch to VBS or PS script.

Comment: To run a batch file invisible you could set it in task scheduler tu run under the system account. But I suspect that the link to "Hkey_current_user" woudn't work in that case. Maybe you would have to use something like:

HKEY_USERS\SID\CONTROL PANEL\DESKTOP...

Substituing SID by the current users SID...